# Highchart bar chart datalabels overlapping issue

Tags: highcharts

I created a bar chart with datalabels. I got the problem if data is too large, datalabel will exceed the chart content. For example, the left datalabel will overlap the xAxis. Can we set the padding of the chart? Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to OS. Can you post a picture illustrating the problem?

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding minPadding/maxPadding:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my labeling problem by adding extra margins, like what this guy is writing about http://cases.azoft.com/data-visualization-highcharts